# What is the best way to communicate from/to application server/webserver in django

Tags: python, django, rpc

So suppose that I have a some processes that doing some hard computations. And this processes controlled through application server.

And I need a web interface to control this processes through application server. What is the best way to do this?

So maybe RPC or expose application server interface through a dbus or a some messaging system like ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ (or RPC based on that messaging system) or using Redis for the publish-subscribe or... what else?

What is the best/standard way to do that? What are the consequences of each solution? Maybe there is some standard framework for django to do that?

Answer (score 2):

For Python/Django one of the most popular ways of doing this is via Celery: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I've considered this already. But the problem is that I don't have a tasks. I have one continously operating task that I need to control. Is celery really suites for this scenario?